# Build NativeScript Blank Project with Minimum Size

Tags: nativescript

I want to Build an apk file (it is a Blank Project) with Minimum size as possible,

as [here](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/nativescript-android-application-package-size-revealed) described:  It could be done by removing unnecessary **ABIs related libs-folders** from `<Project>/platforms/android/libs/jni/`,

My problem is this: in the `<Project>/platforms/android` directory I have just these folders: 
`app` , `build-tools` , `gradle`

what shoulsd I do?

right now my APK file is about 28MB, a size like 12MB would be great for me.

I want to write very simple app with JS ( -- no framework ) and I would like to keep the size as small as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is article is 3 years old. It has been updated. You should check this issue : https://github.com/NativeScript/android-runtime/issues/518

Answer (score 2):

**Android App Bundle** is now the recommended way by Google to create a single file that will distribute only the needed architecture for the user's device. I am recommending it as it is way easier to maintain a single file than the multiple APKs generated with ABI Splits.

[Here is an article](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tooling/publishing/android-app-bundle) on how to create an Android App Bundle in NativeScript.

Answer (score 0):

Edting the file `<Project>/app/App_Resources/Android/app.gradle` to the :

```sh
android {
  defaultConfig {
    generatedDensities = []
    applicationId = "org.nativescript.testapp"

    ndk {
      abiFilters.clear()
    }
  }

  splits {
    abi {
      enable true //enables the ABIs split mechanism
      reset() //reset the list of ABIs to be included to an empty string
      include "x86", "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
      universalApk true
    }
  }
}
```

solved my Problem, new size is about ~10MB, great.